# how to make python append excel file

Tags: python, append

I am scraping data from a particular website every 1 minute. When I do it for the 1st time I want the data to be written to an excel at cell A2 but after sleep of 1 minute when data is fetched, it needs to be written on the last low (say if at the last time 20 records were fetched and data was recorded in excel for cell A2, then after the 1 minute sleep on re-run data should be recorded in cell A21).

Code i am using to fetch is :

```
def fetch_ind():
    while True:
        ind_values = r['data']
        ind_data = pd.DataFrame(ind_values)
    sheet_ind.range("A2").options(index=False, header=False).value = ind_data.drop(
                ['A', 'B', 'C'], axis=1) [['X','Y','Z','timeVal']]

    time.sleep(60.0 - ((time.time() - starttime) % 60.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `pandas` module. In it, you can create the `dictionary` and from it `DataFrame` which you can export to an excel file.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Key1' : 'Value1'}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_excel('example.xlsx')
```